# Software that automatically downloads videos you're watching

Tags: windows, video, web-browser, automation, download-manager

This is a software I used years ago, used to download videos I watch automatically, without clicking anything. It would work in the background and does not slow down the internet. It will capture the videos you're watching (YouTube, Dailymotion, Vimeo, Facebook videos, etc...) automatically. Later, you will see them stored in a folder.

**Used:** Before 2007.

**Operating System:** Windows Vista or XP.

**Worked best on:** YouTube.

**Commercial:** Yes, I remember cracking the software.

**More details:** If you stop watching a video online, it will stop recording.

Any knows that name of this software, or any other similar software?

**Remember:** the notable thing about this software is that:

- There is no download button. It works in the background and saves your time.
- It does not waste internet downloads to re-download. It saves directly during watching. (It either gets it from cache or records it from the screen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not the original program you're looking for, but [VideoCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html) offers similar functionality, in addition to being free.

It basically scans your browser cache and lets you select which videos to keep.

Features based on your criteria:

- Before 2007: **No**
- Windows XP/Vista support: **Yes**
- Works best on YouTube: **Yes**
- Commercial: **No**
- Stops recording if you stop watching a video: **It depends** on whether or not the video has finished downloading (buffering)
- **No download button**: It has a save button instead which keeps the selected videos
- **Does not waste traffic**: It retrieves the videos from your browser cache, so they are downloaded once while watching

I think the major difference between VideoCacheView and the software you describe is that it's not automatic and requires clicking

Comment: Does this handle streamed videos?

Comment: @IraBaxter I have not tested it on streams. However, in the changelog for Version 2.60, it is stated that the support for streams has been added. That requires [GPAC](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/) to be installed

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about [Orbit Downloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_Downloader). The only criteria you listed that Orbit doesn't match is that it is not free.

Comment: The Wikipedia link provided suggests that Orbit Downloader now installs a malware bot.  I suggest would-be users be extremely careful.  If you have actually used this (I decided against it based on this detail), it would be useful to report whether it does have bot-like behavior, if you can detect it.

Answer (score 0):

Your description reminds me of [Replay Media Catcher](http://applian.com/replay-media-catcher/). But I'm uncertain about if it is possible to get one single stream for both watching and archiving. I guess it depends on the settings. My screen shot is from an old version (2011). A new version may have more settings to tweak with.

[image]